# Is list with one String equals (in memory usage) to list with one String and one null object?

Tags: java, list

I want to figure out sometihng.

is this:

```
    List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("abc");
    list.add(null);
```

equals to this

```
    List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("abc");
```

in memory usage?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [initial capacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28%29) of an ArrayList is ten (references). That is to say, the *underlying* array will be of size ten, even if you've only got one entry in your collection. Those references will default to null, and consequently setting the second reference to null will neither affect the internal state of the arraylist (in terms of the underlying array) nor its memory consumption.

If you'd added an *eleventh* item (set to null), the `ArrayList` would expand its capacity, and consequently you'd consume more memory, but rather because the ArrayList had created extra buckets for your `String` references.

From the doc linked above:

> Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of
>   the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at
>   least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an
>   ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth
>   policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has
>   constant amortized time cost.

Answer (score 0):

In this case yes, as ArrayList allocates an array of 10 positions by default (in openjdk).

If you used LinkedList instead, then the answer would be no.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the first list has two elements and the second list has one element so the first list is larger. However most lists default to 10 elements the two lists may be the same size but if the second add required the list to be expanded then it will take more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "it depends".

With the code you have there, running on the Sun JVM, and the way that they've implemented ArrayList, the answer is "yes", they're equal.

This is because by default, an ArrayList starts off with an array of 10 elements. Odds are the most implementations do the same thing.

But if you had an ArrayList with 10 elements, and another with 11, whether the elements are null or not, the 11 element one would consume more RAM because the internal array used to track the elements would have expanded.

Finally, if you were using different List implementation, such as a LinkedList, then the two lists would consume different amounts of memory, as the LinkedList doesn't pre-allocate anything and uses a node wrapper for its elements.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, using an ArrayList with two elements they do.

The initial capacity for an ArrayList is 10 elements, so as long as you add 10 or fewer elements the size of the ArrayList itself is the same (size in memory, not *size()*). When you add the 11th element the the ArrayList will have to grow the internal storage and thus take more memory.

Comment: Size changes, capacity stays same.

Comment: By size I meant the size of the ArrayList in memory, clarified the answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Changed my mind. 
As many people are stating, yes they will take up the same amount of memory at first, once you add enough null's to the point where the initial capacity is reached you will increase your memory size.

I originally thought that because you can *access* the null in the first list that it would lead to more memory, however the null values are there in both cases, and the ability to access them does not affect memory allocation.

Answer (score -2):

No both are not Equals.

```
list [abc,null]
```

Another list stored

```
list [abc]
```

so both are not equal